# Color cells with same value in different columns (different rows) in app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to **color cells** with the same value in different columns. Is there any way to do that in app script?

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question from `I want to color cells with the same value in different columns.` and your sample image. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of unique values
- Create a value to random color [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
- Map the range values to the color using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map)
- Set back the mapped colors array to `range`

```
const colorSameValues = () => {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1'),
    range = sheet.getDataRange(),
    values = range.getValues(),
    set /* unique set */ = new Set(values.flat()),
    map /* values to color map */ = new Map(),
    hex /* random hex color code */ = () =>
      '#' +
      Array(3)
        .fill()
        .map(() =>
          Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
            .toString(16)
            .padStart(2, '0')
        )
        .join('');
  set.delete('');
  set.forEach((val) => map.set(val, hex()));
  range.setBackgrounds(values.map((row) => row.map(map.get.bind(map))));
};
```

Comment: Woaaaa, Thank you, I did it. Merry Christmas!!!!

Comment: @ThảoHương Merry Christmas!

Comment: Hiiiiiiii, I have some problem with your code. When I input new data, the color will change. How to fix it, because I want "if I input new data, keep the old color of the old value and add new color with new data". So sorry because I don't descript that before.

Comment: @ThảoHương That feature would require a significant rewrite of the code. Try to write the code yourself and if you have problems, ask a new question. See [ask], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/

Answer (score 1):

Please define `distinctColors` yourself and make sure there are sufficient colors for your data.

```js
function test() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const values = range.getValues();
  const rows = values.length;
  const cols = values[0].length;
  const colors = new Array(rows).fill().map(row => new Array(cols));
  
  const distinctColors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
  const distinctValues = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      const value = values[i][j];
      if (!distinctValues[value]) { distinctValues[value] = []; }
      distinctValues[value].push({i: i, j:j});
    }
  }
  
  let k = 0;
  for (const array of Object.values(distinctValues)) {
    if (array.length == 1) { continue; }
    for (const v of array) {
      colors[v.i][v.j] = distinctColors[k];
    }
    k++;
  }
  range.setBackgrounds(colors);
}
```

Comment: Woaaaa, Thank you, I did it. Merry Christmas!!!!